# Check if two file names reference to the same file

Tags: c#, file, c#-4.0, io

Is there a way in C# (4.0) to check if two file names reference to the same file, preferably without opening them?

I.e. d:\x.txt should be equal to x.txt or ../x.txt if the the relative path points to d.

Comment: What about symlinks? Junctions?

Comment: Check their size, or dates (like creation, modification). And if all equal, this is the same file.

Comment: Symlinks and junctions I don't think I will encounter.

Comment: Checking every property is not what I want (it's like having file access); maybe I should have added it in my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use [`Path.GetFullPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx) on both names they should resolve to the same string:

```
string fullPath1 = Path.GetFullPath(absolutePath);
string fullPath2 = Path.GetFullPath(relativePath);
```

Then `fullPath1` should equal `fullPath2` if they reference the same file. Make sure that you do a case insensitive comparison as Windows filenames are case insensitive.

Comment: This doesn't handle the case-insensitivity of filenames in Windows. On the current .NET Framework implementation, `Path.GetFullPath(@"c:\a.txt")` is not equal to `Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\A.TXT")` even though they are (probably) the same file.

Comment: @Carl the equals test should be done using the correct comparison options of course.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this works for you?

```
FileInfo file1 = new FileInfo(@"D:\x.txt");
FileInfo file2 = new FileInfo(@"..\x.txt");

if (file1.FullName == file2.FullName) {
    // yes, they match..
```

Comment: I think it works, but I don't know if file access is involved here, so I rather go to the GetFullPath solution. However +1 for a working solution.

Comment: File access is deferred until you attempt to access a property that requires it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use `Path.GetFullPath` and then a case-insensitive compare:

```
var file1 = Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\TEMP\A.TXT");
var file2 = Path.GetFullPath(@"a.txt"); // Assuming current directory is C:\TEMP

// Test 1 (good)
if (file1.Equals(file2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
   Console.WriteLine("Test 1: they match");
}

// Test 2 (fails when file paths differ by case)
if (file1 == file2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Test 2: they match");
}
```

Most people run .NET on case-insensitive filesystems, so comparing paths that differ only by case using the `==` operator will not produce the desired result.